# How to retrieve signal strength and bearer information on dual SIM devices below API 24

Tags: android

So far I have the below code to retrieve information from the `TelephonyManager` on dual SIM devices but it will only work on API level 24+ (N+)

```
SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = (SubscriptionManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
List<SubscriptionInfo> subscriptionInfos = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
for (SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo : subscriptionInfos) {
    int subId = subscriptionInfo.getSubscriptionId();
    TelephonyManager manager = telephonyManager.createForSubscriptionId(subId);
    // etc
}
```

(Can't test the above as I don't have a dual SIM Nougat device)

How can I retrieve a `TelephonyManager` instance for both SIMs or at least retrieve signal strength and bearer information?

Comment: Hello, have you been able to find a solution? I have the same problem.